# Is there a way to merge two trained neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning

Lets say I pick some network layout (recurrent and/or deep is fine if it matters I'm interested to know why), then make two neural networks A and B using that layout that are initially identical.

Now I go and train A on one dataset and someone else trains B on a different (but similar) dataset. As a concrete example, lets say we train A to classify a subset of [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) and B to classify a different subset of [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html).

There is what is known as transfer learning, where a network trained on one dataset might do better or train faster on a different dataset, in theory because it has some ideas developed about the structure of the first problem that is in the structure of the second problem. So a trivial way to classify a new subset of CIFAR-10 is to make a dense layer as input that is then connected to both A and B, then you take say the average of their outputs.

However that requires increasing the size of the network. Is there a way to "merge" A and B into a network that preserves much of the same training in both into a network C that has the same layout as A and B?

Comment: If A and B have same architecture completely, you can take the average of two weights to create the new weight in C. Same for biases. There is not really any other way if you don't want to have a different architecture for C.

Comment: I think that the crucial problem here is figuring out how to merge the weights on the same model, but retain some bound on the loss.